# What is the relationship between .gconf, .gnome2, .cache, .local, and other dot-file hierarchies in my home directory?

Tags: gnome, files, gconf, configuration-management, dconf

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14535/whats-the-local-folder-for-in-my-home-directory/14536#14536), `.local .cache` and `.config` are, by convention, configuration storage locations adopted by Gnome and Ubuntu.

Are `.gnome .gnome2` and `.gconf` therefore legacy configuration directories, or are they supposed to co-exist?
And does the adoption of dconf alter these dot-file application config conventions?

Finally, what is the relation of the gconf-editor data settings to these directories?  Do .gnome/.gconf contain the same info that gconf-editor accesses?

Updates: 
XDG has been pointed to as the reason for .cache, .local, and .config.

This [question on dconf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-and-what-is-its-function) advises that dconf will be the replacement for gconf,
as documented on [Gnome.org](http://live.gnome.org/dconf) . 
Furthermore,  [João](https://askubuntu.com/users/742/joao-pinto) says that dconf is the

> GNOME technology used to store
>   application settings. [...] dconf is
>   the GNOME3 replacement for gconf which
>   has not been maintained for some time.
>   dconf is also expected to bring
>   performance improvements over gconf
>   (relevant for applications startup).

I expect, based on that that there will be a somewhat anarchic migration path from gconf settings to dconf.  I would love to hear any additional perspectives.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.local`, `.cache`, and `.config` are part of the FreeDesktop [Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). They should not actually be hard-coded but instead use the environment variables (i.e. `$XDG_DATA_HOME`, `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`, and `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`). There are [GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-user-config-dir) and [Python](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pyxdg) wrappers for the spec that may be helpful as well. Here's an example in Python:

```python
>>> import xdg.BaseDirectory
>>> print xdg.BaseDirectory.xdg_data_home
/home/andrew/.local/share
>>> print xdg.BaseDirectory.xdg_config_home
/home/andrew/.config
>>> print xdg.BaseDirectory.xdg_cache_home
/home/andrew/.cache
```

`.gnome` and `.gnome2` are indeed deprecated and should not be used. These were used by libgnome's [gnome-config module](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libgnome/stable/libgnome-gnome-config.html).

`.gconf` does indeed contain the settings that `gconf-editor` accesses as xml files. For instance, compare the output of the following commands:

```
gconftool -a /desktop/gnome/applications/browser

cat ~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/applications/browser/%gconf.xml
```

Comment: I came across your answer when trying to find how to find the configuration directory from a gtk application. For other programmers who come after me there is a gtk(glib) wrapper which uses XDG on Linux and also handles MS Windows. Specific information here: http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-user-config-dir

Comment: Right you are. I was mostly just being descriptive in this answer, not providing hands on examples for a programmer. I'll update the answer to add a little more info for those who stumble across this.

Answer (score 5):

The proper phrasing should be that .local, .cache, etc are part of the XDG Base Directory Specification of FreeDesktop, http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html.

The XDG Base Directory Specification is a standard, and is followed by KDE and other compliant environments.

Comment: What does it mean to be compliant?  Is there a mandate to convert apps using a different specification to the XDG one, or otherwise to leave them out of the Gnome/KDE base install?  If so, is the mandate enforced?  Are non-compliant third-party apps flagged by someone, or is the existence of different config conventions/dirs assumed to be a given, that is, something that will continue until voluntarily abandoned by all ecosystem developers?   I don't have KDE installed, but base Ubuntu/Gnome for my 10.10 system has the XDG dirs you mention.  Perhaps this is voluntary compliance?

Comment: For the most part it is voluntary compliance, but there has been discussion in the past about making XDG compliance a "goal" for all application in the default install.

Comment: It is voluntary compliance, but users can (and many do) fill bug reports on non-compliant apps requesting them to adhere to the standard. Un-cluttering their $HOME folder is one of the greatest benefits of the XDG standard, so user pressure is usually quite high on legacy apps.