# Will applications be putting user data in ~/.config instead of just ~?

Tags: configuration, configuration-management

Are there any plans to have applications store data from each user in home/user/.config instead of just home/user/ and their respective directories?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/22361/what-is-the-relationship-between-gconf-gnome2-cache-local-and-other-dot-f/22544#22544 for some clarifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [my answer to a releated question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22361/what-is-the-relationship-between-gconf-gnome2-cache-local-and-other-dot-f/22544#22544), `~/.config` is part of the [FreeDesktop Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

According to the spec, "user data" should not actually be put in `~/.config` at all.

- `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is where user
  specific configuration files should
  be stored.
- `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is where user
  specific data files should be stored.
- `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` defaults to
  `~/.config`
- `$XDG_DATA_HOME` defaults to
  `~/.local/share`

As I say in a comment in that question: compliance is voluntary, but there has been discussion in the past about making XDG compliance a "goal" for all application in the default install.