# Accidentaly removed ~/.local/share

Tags: files

I accidentaly removed `~/.local/share` while i wanted to delete just a folder inside this folder. Do I have to reinstall my system? Or is there another way of fixing this?

Comment: You can try to recover parts of the deleted file by following http://askubuntu.com/questions/676242/how-to-recover-deleted-files-in-ubuntu-using-live-usb-based-on-filetype and then checking if your system works.

Comment: My system is still running so that is a plus

Comment: OK then you can try the link to try to recover the missing files

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing system-critical in ~/.local/share: see [Whats the .local folder for in my Home Directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14535/whats-the-local-folder-for-in-my-home-directory)

Comment: No need for system reinstallation, you might have to redo some personal settings/info, though. E.g. files recently opened. Nothing critical.